# I need to run an async function from a non-async function in order (sync) - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Yes, it's a bad idea, a terrible idea.

I'm trying to make this:

```js
async function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    console.log('called 3');
}

console.log('called 1');

(async () => {
    console.log('called 2');
    await delay(5000);
    console.log('called 4');
})();

console.log('called 5');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwCYFMA2wYAFALYgBcMECpARrgE4CUVACo+qaiLgDwA3dKmwA+GAG8AUDFkxgAd2Cpk1XApgcuPXMUYwAvON7IAKqlK50CZHoA0Mcs2YBuGXKiYQ6fLgB0+OgA5sQA5FDA+L7YMADMoa5SAL5SUp4Q3r4BwWERUbgxAIwJblLEoJCwxMyG4tJyMOmZ-oEh4ZHRMABMJe6yisqqeIQkAKwADJOJDU0+LTnt+TEALL1JzNWls1mtuR0FMKMlQA)

Output this:

```
called 1
called 2
called 3
called 4
called 5
```

Instead of this:

```
called 1
called 2
called 5
called 3
called 4
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Possible, sure (anything can be *eventually* modified into something else), but it sounds like you have restrictions. What parts of it are you permitted to change? Put `called 5` in a `.then` after the IIFE?

Comment: the order of console.log's you want is impossible, unless you put the `console.log(5)` somewhere else - i.e. where it won't be executed until asynchronous code completes - what the above comment suggests is `(async () => { ... etc ...})().then(() => console.log('called 5'));`

Answer (score 0):

I took out the typescript tags and ran directly in the browser
altering the following lines

```
async function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
```

to direct JS

```
async function delay(ms) {
```

and it works as you would expect by awaiting in order ...

```js
async function delay(ms) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    console.log('called 3');
}

console.log('called 1');

(async () => {
    console.log('called 2');
    await delay(5000);
   await console.log('called 4');
   
console.log('called 5');
})();
```

It is important to remember that async functions are asynchronously so there would be no other way of calling  `console.log('called 5');` in order without placing it in the async function or using a **then** statement... I prefer the easier way of just putting the call in the async function..

Answer (score 0):

It's not that is a "bad idea", is that you cannot use the syntax you want. But you can definitely execute `console.log('called 5')` after the `async` function; it's just you cannot use `await` (given that you're not in an `async` function):

```
async function delay(ms) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    console.log('called 3');
}

console.log('called 1');

(async () => {
    console.log('called 2');
    await delay(2000);
    console.log('called 4');
})().then(
 ()=> console.log('called 5')
);
```

Don't forget that an async function returns an implicit Promise as result; so you can use `then` to obtain the result you want.

This, or you wrap everything in an `async function` so you can use `await`; but I understand from your question this is somehow not an option.